# Python crawler is not crawling all sites

Tags: python

I'm trying to get links from websites through this code

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
def get_links(max_pages):
    page = 1
    while page <= max_pages:
        address = 'http://hamariweb.com/mobiles/nokia_mobile-phones1.aspx?Page=' + str(page)
        source_code = requests.get(address)
        plain_text = source_code.text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text)
        for link in soup.findAll('a', {'class': 'TextClass8pt'}):
            href = link.get("href")
            print(href)

        page += 1

get_links(3)
```

and it's giving expected output. But when I tried this

```
address = 'http://propakistani.pk/category/cellular/page/' + str(page)
```

for link in `soup.findAll('a', {'class': 'aa_art_hdng'}):`

It's showing this error

> TypeError: getresponse() got an unexpected keyword argument 'buffering'

I also tried another site but that time neighter it showed any output nor any error. Why it's showing proper output with different sites? Is there any problem with my code? Please help me. 
Thanks

Comment: but not working for me

Comment: `address = 'http://propakistani.pk/category/cellular/page/' + str(1)`   there is no tag with `'a', {'class': 'TextClass8pt'}`

Comment: change condition to `for i in soup.findAll('a'):` and check

Comment: Worst title for a question ever. Why do you think other people ask their question here, because their code is giving them their desired output?

Comment: @Raza Well done! Someone even gave you a +1. Welcome at Stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 1):

there is **No Tag Match** with this condition `soup.findAll('a', {'class': 'TextClass8pt'})`

Try following

**Demo**:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def get_links(max_pages):
    page = 1

    while page <= max_pages:
        address = 'http://propakistani.pk/category/cellular/page/' + str(page)
        source_code = requests.get(address)
        plain_text = source_code.text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text)
        for link in soup.findAll('a'):
            href = link.get("href")
            print(href)

        page += 1

get_links(3)
```

---

**Or**

There are `a` tag with class value `aa_loop_h2a`
e.g.
`<a class="aa_loop_h2a" href="http://propakistani.pk/2015/04/20/mobile-data-usage-in-pakistan-grows-600-during-2014/" title="Mobile Data Usage in Pakistan Grows 600% During 2014">Mobile Data Usage in Pakistan Grows 600% During 2014</a>`

So try with `soup.findAll('a', {'class': 'aa_loop_h2a'})` condition.

Comment: class value is `aa_loop_h2a`

Comment: @Raza: No, Can you pass me your code on Stack overflow or vivekbsable@gmail.com